# Ordering elements in a list by a chain

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have a database of elements with a parameter that specifies the ordering, with properties like:

```
 ID
 Name
 Order
```

Let's say order is an integer - it is easy to query and order by Order. However, if I want to insert a new element in between this list, I have to go renumber everything below it - worst case scenario is when I want to push an element to the top.

So I have this idea by ordering elements by a chain. That is, I have one table with my Elements :

```
ID
Name
```

And then I have a second table with Edges :

```
StartNode
EndNode
```

And this just defines which element is connected to which other element. This way, when I want to insert an element, I just need to remove an edge and put in another one - I don't need to reorder the whole list.

But is there an efficient way to query out to get an ordered list from these two tables? Does this approach have some sort of name?

Comment: I've never tried, and I don't know the performance cost so I'm not going to post this as an answer: What if you used `float` instead of `int` and just insert in between.  I.E. if you want to insert between 5 and 6 you'd create your new item with an `Order` of 5.5

Comment: This is what you're after, you can probably convert the query results straight to a linked list, but if not you can definitely convert arrays to LinkedLists. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Are there any advantages to having your database set up like that? These types of my questions make me think there is a better approach.

Comment: I'm simply interested in whether there's some way I can avoid having to renumber the entire list, as that could be a bottleneck for very large lists. 
For my purpose, I would rather eat the inefficiency when loading the list, and then have the reordering be fast and lightweight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question! As pointed out by starlight54, this approach is called a *linked list*, in particular a *doubly linked list*. Although I think that strictly speaking, in a linked list the references to other nodes are part of the nodes themselves. In db terms: the database record itself has foreign keys to the next and previous nodes (i.e. a doubly linked list). But that doesn't really matter for the bad news that comes now.

You're absolutely right that linked lists allow for very efficient insertion (and deletion) of nodes. But the bad news is that ordering is highly inefficient.

The point is that linked lists require sequential access: first you have to find the first node, then the next node, then the next node, ... There is no way to get the ordered list in one SQL statement containing an `ORDER BY`. SQL – designed for set operations – and sequential access are two different worlds.

The worst approach would be to query each node separately from the database. An improvement would be to fetch all nodes and build an ordered list in memory, but it's never going to be pleasant.

So all and all I'd stick to this `Order` column. Usually data are read far more often than modified, so optimizing the updating speed at the expense of easy access is not the most obvious thing to do.